# How do I back up my Pokemon Y cartridge?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I want to do a Wonderlocke challenge on my Pokemon Y version but I'd like to not lose my data because I have a Pokedex of 425. Can someone help?

Comment: There is no official way, but despite the downvotes, satanas has the only true answer for your question.

Comment: You might be able to put them all in the PokeBank, then start (only if your dex of 425 was all currently being owned by you).

Answer (score 2):

From [Nintendo's support page](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/70/~/how-to-back-up-save-data):

[image]

Obviously, this means that only downloaded E-Shop titles will be able to be back upped. If you had a downloaded Pokemon X/Y game, this would have worked, but from what you have mentioned, you have a cartridge-based version, meaning you cannot.

Comment: The Back Up Save Data software also prevents you from backing up certain titles. For instance, Pokemon X/Y cannot be backed up with it.

Comment: The past participle of "backup" or "back up" is "backed up," just so you know.

Answer (score -3):

If you're willing to cheat, you can back up your game using an [Action Replay](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CQ9L1Z6).